# Associative Array check if login combination is correct

Tags: php

This is my very first post and question on this website. I'm working on my school assignment now and I have to check if the login credentials are the same as the ones that are listed in my associative array. I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

This is my PHP code:

```php
// Create associative array

$loginCombinations = array("Lucas"=>"lucas3284", "Bob"=>"bob9584", "Frits"=>"frits1842", "Kees"=>"kees1394", "Sjakie"=>"sjakie1953", "Bas"=>"bas6382", "Peter"=>"peter2391", "Robbie"=>"robbie1289", "Jan"=>"jan1462", "Tim"=>"tim9324");

// Create message (login succesful / login failed)

$message = "";

// Create foreach loop

foreach($loginCombinations as $username => $password)
{

}
```

and this is my HTML code:

```html
<form action="login.php" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo $message;
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="username">username</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="password">password</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change `GET` method to `POST` as `<form action="login.php" method="POST">` to send the data in request payload rather than as GET parameters for security.

So, you would put `if` condition in the `foreach` loop to check and echo success message accordingly.

```
<?php 

$found = false;
foreach($loginCombinations as $username => $password){
    if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
        echo "Yes, user found!!";
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$found){
    echo "No user found!!";
}
```

---

**Update:**

Add a `name` attribute to your submit button say `submit` like `<input type="submit" name="submit">`. Now, you will need to add an additional `if` condition to check if data was actually posted.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $found = false;
    foreach($loginCombinations as $username => $password){
        if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
            echo "Yes, user found!!";
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$found){
        echo "No user found!!";
    }
}
```

---

**Update #2:**

As pointed out by `@Nigel Ren`, you can simply do an `isset` check.

```
if(isset($loginCombinations[$_POST['username']],$loginCombinations[$_POST['password']])){
   echo "user found";
}else{
   echo "user not found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username` when I load the page. I did everything you typed there.

Answer (score 1):

As your array is indexed by the user name, there is no need to do a loop.  First check if the user name element is set and then check the password for a match...

```
$userName = $_GET['username'] ?? '';
$message = "";

if ( isset($loginCombinations[$userName]) && 
        $loginCombinations[$userName] === $_GET['password']) {
    $message = "user login correct";
}
else    {
    $message = "user login incorrect";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately a foreach loop is required in my school assignment ...